# Print value of a particular field for all records in given JSON (NoSQL)

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and NoSQL. I have created a program that will get data from firebase. The output that I am getting is :

```
{
    "League1": {
        "LeagueName": "League1",
        "SubLeagueName": [
            "SubLeague1",
            "SubLeague2",
            "SubLeague3"
        ]
    },
    "League3": {
        "LeagueName": "League2",
        "SubLeagueName": [
            "SubLeague1",
            "SubLeague2",
            "SubLeague3"
        ]
    } }
```

I have used put statement and League1,League3 are primary keys. Now I want to create a table that show LeagueName for all the records. How to do that?

Comment: What means a `table`? Is it some type of data?

Comment: I was trying to populate my listview using that data.

Comment: Which data types can accept your listview? Or do you just need to convert the input data to a different data type? What is the final data type? Can you give an example of the output you need?

Comment: I wanted to create one List<String> to store leaguenames for all the leagues. I have answered this question. I am iterating through each dictionary, getting value of league name and putting it inside a List.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by :
1) Converting dynamic output to Map i.e.

response as Map

2) Iterating through all the keys of this map.
3) Querying Map with each key for each record, then querying each record for "LeagueName".

```
for (var i in responseMap.keys){
        leagueNameArray.add(responseMap[i]["LeagueName"]);
      }
```